# How can I protest question closure?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed

What is the way to protest question closure in case I don't want to alter it?
The question is well formed and even answered. Some people marked the answer as useful, so the question could help others. What is the reason answered with a useful answer, the question could be closed?

Well, if some expert can't get it while the community can, what is the way to correct him/her?

Comment: One way to do this is to post a question here, on Meta. But if you wish to do this, you will want to be more specific, including a link to the disputed question and including a detailed enumeration of why you feel that the closure was unjust. For best result, you will want to stick to facts and objective data as much as possible and try to keep emotion out of your post. Also, when coming here, best to keep an open mind towards opposing viewpoints. They are guaranteed to come, but that is one of the beauties of meta.

Comment: Also, one word of caution: you will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: “What is the way to protest question closure in case I don't want to alter it?” - You don’t; If you’re unwilling to improve your question. Why should your question be reopened?

Comment: @SecurityHound: while I agree that the close-question system works well for the most part, it is far from infallible as your comment above suggests. Our voting should based on concrete criteria but in the final analysis is always subjective, and there are going to be times when good questions, questions that don't require improvement, will be closed. Whether this is what happened to the OP may never be known, since they posted a "tease" question on meta without denouement, which seems a bit unfair and unsatisfying to me.

Comment: If this is about the question I believe it is, the term "_Virtually sequentially concatenate_" is quite unclear. I had to read the answer to understand what you were asking. Maybe you can state it better as "How do I iterate over two C++ std::vectors of objects of different types without concatenating them?"

Comment: "My question consists of two parts" Downvote close vote.

Answer (score 16):

> What is the way to protest question closure in case I don't want to alter it?

By posting here about the specific question. Beware that this is likely to invoke Meta effect.

That said: please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a collaboratively edited library. "I don't want to alter it" expresses a mindset of ownership, but the question no longer belongs to you. By posting, you [grant a Creative Commons BY-SA license to your work](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

> The question is well formed

You are not the one who gets to judge this.

> and even answered.

This is not relevant. The purpose of question closure is to prevent future answers from coming in, until the question is in a state where it meets the site standards and should, per policy, receive answers. The fact that someone, or even multiple people answer *despite that* the question does not meet the standards described in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), does not obviate those standards. Instead, it puts the answerers in the wrong - as described in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Of course, the standards admit subjectivity, and generally need to be assessed by community members. That's why I don't say "rule" in this discussion, and why we don't directly punish people for getting it wrong.

> Some people marked the answer as useful, so question could help others. What is the reason answered with useful answer question could be closed?

Because "answered with a useful answer" is **not the standard**.

The standard is that the question shall be **all of**:

- on topic;
- objective (not soliciting opinion like "the best way" to do something, nor soliciting a recommendation for something third-party);
- understandable (including: written in English);
- a single, specific question that can reasonably be answered in a single post;
- *straightforwardly about the thing it claims to be about, and not about the "X" of an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/)*;
- *for how-to questions, explained with clear, specific, understandable requirements*;
- for debugging questions, accompanied by a proper [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example);
- not a duplicate;
- regarding a problem others could plausibly encounter or wish to solve (i.e. is "reproducible") caused by something that is not idiosyncratic to your own code but which others could commonly get wrong in the same way (i.e. is not "caused by a typo")

My personal assessment is that the question you appear to be talking about (I assume you mean your own) fails the points in italics.

It does not logically follow that a question "answered with a useful answer", "could help others" in the sense that we are concerned with. Useful questions that are usefully part of a Q&A library, need to be clear, focused and *searchable*. They need to *not* reflect XY problems from the asker.

> Well, if some expert can't get it while the community can, what is the way to correct him?

First: "some expert" did not close your question. Only moderators can act unilaterally to close a question for the reason that it is unclear; "experts" (formally defined: people with a gold tag badge in one of the original tags on the question) can only unilaterally close the question as a duplicate.

Second: now it seems that we have gone from disputing an action, to assuming that you are in the right and that others are in the wrong and should be "corrected". This is not the way to sway opinion in your favour on Meta.

Third: just as we don't directly punish people for asking unclear questions, we certainly are not going to directly punish people for incorrectly assessing questions as unclear. We're far more democratic than that.

Just as a note: there are [27](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) moderators for all of Stack Overflow. That compares to [more than 20 **million**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1734025) users. (User IDs run a bit higher than that, I guess mainly because of destroyed spammer accounts and manual account deletions.) The moderators deserve to be cut some slack.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I want to avoid Meta Effect, so I don't like to post the link. Can we discuss the specific one to one somewhere in chat? On your answers: (1) yes, I am not the one to judge this, but why he (expert) could be one who just closes, not even judges. I can't judge alone, he could close alone. Strange. (2) Yes, question doesn't belong to me, but being the member of community I think that it is well formed; this is one opinion, equal to others. Why one person overpower this one opinion plus opinions of others who marked it useful? I am fine to improve, but I can't see how.

Comment: Moderators do not act on their own initiative, but in response to reports through the flagging system and review queues. The normal process requires three votes from users with 3000+ reputation, and can be undone by three other people voting to reopen - also with 3000+ reputation - if you edit the question to address the problem that was described. Your opinion is not being overpowered and the pro-closing faction does not have special privileges. Aside from that, marking the *answer* useful **is not** marking the *question* useful. And nobody is required to explain their upvotes or downvotes.